# Change display image position on Windows using an nVidia card

Tags: windows, laptop-display, nvidia-graphics-card

I am using a resolution less then the native resolution of my laptop monitor and would like to specify the position (h-pos and v-pos) of the display image on my screen freely.

I am using Windows and a nVidia graphics card. The nVidia Control Panel only allows me to change size (resolution) and scaling but not position - the image is always centered on the screen.

Comment: I don't think this is possible at all. I am curious as to the possible reasons as to why you would want to do this...

Comment: That would be unfortunate... is there maybe any way of controlling your graphics card behaviour in more detail then what the GUI offers? In my case I damaged a couple of rows of pixels at the bottom of the screen and I'd like to only use the "upper" part of the screen (basically cutting off 15 pixels from the bottom). For this I have to move the screen position up if I don't want to cut away twice the amount (additionally from the top).

Comment: Can you not work around the damage or replace the screen?

Comment: Of course I could replace the screen. But I'd much rather like to enable some setting somewhere then to buy a piece of hardware. On Linux there is xrandr that controls screen behaviour in detail. No equivalent on Windows? And of course I could also just live with it, however for some applications the bottom couple of pixels are necessary and I wouldn't like to resize every application because of this.